# PyQT4 or PySide tutorial about QtNetworking and QtWebkit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to find a PyQT or PySide tutorial that covers QtNetworking and QtWebKit, I can only find tutorials about QtCore and some tutorials how to create bottons and other similar gui. But I'm looking a bit different thing.

Comment: So what's the question?
Try reading Qt's own documentation on the mentioned, they will surely suffice because PyQt/PySide are just python-ized versions of Qt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not really the answer to your question - when faced with the same basic problem - here are the resources I used to get up and running:

- Although a little behind version-wise, a great book with lots of examples and practical design methodology - [Rapid UI Programming with Python and Qt](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html)  - It's written for PyQt, but easily applicable for PySide with minor changes.
- [pyside-examples](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples) - The pyside-examples collection was usually my first stop in figuring out to write PySide code. They have Python analogs of the C++ examples and cover most subject matters. However, specifically, the *qwebkit* content is brief at best.
- [PySide API documentation](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/) - The PySide content used to be easily available at pyside.org (or something similar..), now it's at a funky [github address](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/) - http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide, which for any paranoid URL hawks out there you can verify as published @ the new Qt project webpage http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide
- If you don't know C++ Qt and you're picking up pyside first - consider familiarizing yourself with the C++ content. There are a lot more tutorials and explanations regarding the C++ code than PySide (Or PyQt). If you understand MVC, signal/slot, async networking, and UI doodads - translating from PySide to Qt C++ won't be painful. But without those skills, the learning curve can be a bit steep initially. There's some stuff to consider like Qt's UI event loop, Qt threads vs. Python threads, etc. (When in doubt, do it the 'Qt way')
- Look at other people's programs - github, googlecode and gitorious have a fair amount of PySide/PyQt projects to pour through.
- If you want a 'kitchen sink' example that exercises a heap of PyQt/PySide's capabilities - I'd suggest [spyderlib](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/). it's tough to 'extract' things out of it to reuse, but it does give you a nice foundation to start making changes, re-running the code and observing the changes.

Comment: The [PyQt Wiki](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/FrontPage) also has a lot of useful links.